# Why the value of the list changes when the function ends?

Tags: python

So , I have a this function:

```
def Undo_Action(expenses_list ,expenses_lists_que,current_position):
    '''
    Undo the last performed action
    Input:expenses_list - The current list of expenses
          expenses_lists_que - The list containing the instances of last lists
          current_possition- The posion in the que where our current expenses_list is
    '''
    if len(expenses_lists_que)>0:
        expenses_list=deepcopy(expenses_lists_que[current_position-1])
        current_position=current_position-1
    else:
        print("You din not performed any actions yet!")
    print ("Label 1:" ,expenses_list)
    return current_position
```

And I call it in this function

```
def Execute_Main_Menu_Action( expenses_list, action, expenses_lists_que,current_position):
    '''
    Executes a selected option from the main menu
    Input: The expenses list on which the action will be performed
           The action which should be exectued
    Output: The expenses list with the modifications performed
    '''
    if action == 1 :
        Add_Expense(expenses_list)
    elif action== 5:
        Show_Expenses_List(expenses_list)
    elif action== 2:
        Remove_Expense_Menu( expenses_list)
    elif action== 3:
        Edit_Expense_Menu(expenses_list)
    elif action==4:
        Obtain_Data_Menu (expenses_list)
    elif action==6:
        current_position=Undo_Action(expenses_list ,expenses_lists_que,current_position)
    print("Label 2:" , expenses_list)

    return current_position
```

Why the list expenses_list lose it's value when the function Undo_Action ends. I mean when I print the expenses_list at the Label 1 the modifications are performed but when the function exits the modification did not remain so at Label 2 I have a different list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because now `expenses_list` in `Undo_Action` is referring to another list after you do `expenses_list=deepcopy(expenses_lists_que[current_position-1])`.

What you need to do is to change that line to `expenses_list[:]=deepcopy(expenses_lists_que[current_position-1])`. In this case, `expenses_list` will be revised in place instead of referring to another list.

Because of this, if you write `expenses_list = [1,2]` inside the function, it will NOT affect outside `expenses_list` since `expenses_list` in function is now referring to another object (list). But, if you write `expenses_list[:] = [1,2]` , or `expenses_list[0], expenses_list[1] = 1, 2`, your outside `expenses_list` will be changed.